# How to use Redshift without the geoclue2 provider?

Tags: redshift

Redshift seems to use the [geoclue-2.0](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/158) package to get the location specification automatically upon its launch.

This usually works. However, whenever I don't have an active internet connection from the start, Redshift is unable to get my location and returns the error `Unable to get location from provider.`

For the case of a missing internet connection, how can I make Redshift use a custom location setting and not make it try to use geoclue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide your location (in terms of decimal degrees) to `redshift` using the `-l` switch, and it no longer needs `geoclue`.

In my case, I [searched](https://duckduckgo.com) for "MY_CITY latitude longitude", entered dateandtime.info page, found the latitude and longitude of my city in *decimal degrees*, and provided them to `redshift` as indicated in the help and `man` page, namely `redshift -l LAT:LON`.

As an example, for [New York](http://dateandtime.info/citycoordinates.php?id=5128581), your can run `redshift -l 40.71427:-74.00597`.

Comment: All right, so I run that command and it doesn't work: `Malformed argument. Failed to set manual option. Try '-l manual:help' for more information.`

Comment: Copy and pasted the command exactly and the man page agrees with what you said. I'm quite stumped.

Comment: After I searched I found [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/915273), so it seems to be an incorrect configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix it by editing my configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [my free bash](https://github.com/pastet89/redshift-geoclue-bash-patch) patch using a `jq` workaround on GutHub.